# How to get facebook user information in server side?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a mobile app, all my html are in local, it talks with server with http request.

Clearly I can not using the JS SDK since the html is localhost,

also, I can not use the PHP SDK since user not directly load the PHP file on the server.

Then how should I do to integrate Facebook API to my mobile app?

Please kindly suggest me some directions.

Comment: You can try integrating with mobile SDK for Facebook

Comment: do you mean the android and iPhone SDK?

Comment: Yup, I think these SDKs could help you. So have you checked them out?